# Disable MongoDB restart on upgrade (RPM package)

Tags: mongodb, rpm, yum

MongoDB RPM packages (provided by official repo.mongodb.org repository, as of version 3.4.1) automatically and unconditionally restart server on package upgrade. This behaviour is hardcoded into postun handler:

```
if test $1 -ge 1                                                                                                                                                                                                    
then                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  /usr/bin/systemctl restart mongod >/dev/null 2>&1 || :                                                                                                                                                            
fi
```

This is an inconvenient and dangerous behaviour, especially when you use configuration management tools to set up your servers. For example, I'd like to run a full Ansible playbook to set up my servers first, and then restart MongoDB manually one by one to have full control of the situation.

Is there any way to alter or disable this? Alternative MongoDB packages, maybe? Or some obscure yum/rpm command option to disable scriptlets?

I'm aware that I can switch to simple .tar.gz installation, but this is the last resort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you first download the rpm and install it manually using `rpm`; you can use the `--nopostun` option:

```
rpm -Uvh mongodb***rpm --nopostun
```

from the rpm man page:

> ```
>   --noscripts
>   --nopre
>   --nopost
>   --nopreun
>   --nopostun
>   --nopretrans
>   --noposttrans
>          Don't execute the scriptlet of the same name.  The --noscripts option is equivalent to
>          --nopre --nopost --nopreun --nopostun --nopretrans --oposttrans
>          and turns off the execution of the corresponding %pre, %post, %preun, %postun %pretrans, and %posttrans scriptlet(s).
> ```

afaik `yum`cannot handle the `--nopostun` and other flags.

Comment: I'm currently looking into yum-plugin-tsflags, which presumably can handle this.

Comment: yes indeed that might help you; but beware; If you run `yum upgrade --nopostun` (supposing yum understands); he will probably disable all postun scripts for all rpms he will install...

Comment: yum-plugin-tsflags works for me like this: yum -y --setopt=tsflags=noscripts install mongodb-org